# ggplot Bar Chart with empty tick marks

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, bar-chart

I am creating a shiny app to track the yearly budget of a sector over 5 years. The first two years are submitted and plotted as a bar chart but I want to show the remaining five years on the x axis without putting 0's in the dataframe, as they submit their budget yearly through a form on a shiny app. If I added 0's to the dataframe when they submit their budget it would not autopopulate and display the correct chart which is the purpose of the shiny app.

Current data frame:

| ACSyear | ACSbudget |
| --- | --- |
| FY22 | 10000 |
| FY23 | 15000 |

Current code:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(ACSbudgdata, aes(ACSyear, ACSbudget)) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
      ylab("Budget Amount (dollars)") + xlab("Fiscal Year") +
      theme(legend.position = "right") +
      scale_y_continuous(label = comma) +
      ggtitle("Strategic Plan Tracking: Aquatic Conservation Budget")
```

What I would like the chart to look like while keeping the dataframe the same:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to set categories to be displayed via the `limits` argument of `scale_x_discrete`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ACSbudgdata <- data.frame(
           ACSyear = c("FY22", "FY23"),
         ACSbudget = c(10000L, 15000L)
)

ggplot(ACSbudgdata, aes(ACSyear, ACSbudget)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  ylab("Budget Amount (dollars)") + xlab("Fiscal Year") +
  theme(legend.position = "right") +
  scale_y_continuous(label = scales::comma) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = paste0("FY", 22:26)) +
  ggtitle("Strategic Plan Tracking: Aquatic Conservation Budget")
```

[image]